# PostgreSQL Update Issue With Quotation('')

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, postgresql, sql-update

I'm using PostgreSQL & Codeigniter. There is a table called folio in the database. It has few columns containing `remarks1, remarks2, remarks3` as well. Data for the all the other columns are inserted when the INSERT statement executes for the 1st time.

When I try to execute below UPDATE statement later for the below 3 columns, `remarks1` column get updated correctly. But `remarks2, remarks3` columns are updated with `''`.

```
UPDATE "folio" SET "remarks1" = 'test remark', "remarks2" = '', "remarks3" = '' WHERE "id" = '51';
```

Given that `remarks1, remarks2, remarks3` columns data type is `character varying`. I'm using Codeigniter active records. At a time all 3 columns could be updated else single column could be updated depending on the user input.

What could be the issue? How can I fix this? Why columns are updated with `''`?

As requested the php array in CI would be below

```
$data     = array(
     'remark1' => $this->input->post('remark1'),
     'remark2' => $this->input->post('remark1'),
     'remark3' => $this->input->post('remark1')
);
```

Function which saves the data contains below two lines only

```
$this->db->where('id', $folio_id);
$this->db->update('folio', $data);
```

Comment: UPDATE "folio" SET "remarks1" = 'test remark', "remarks2" = 'moreinfo', "remarks3" = 'minfopart2' WHERE "id" = '51'; ???

Comment: ` WHERE "id" = '51';` is `id` a char or varchar column ? when not: remove the quotes: `WHERE "Id" = 51` (BTW: have you been exposed to mysql in a previous life?)

Comment: It's generated by CI :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those columns are updated with `''` because you tell them to?
Let's take a closer look at the query

```
UPDATE "folio"
SET
    "remarks1" = 'test remark',
    "remarks2" = '',
    "remarks3" = ''
WHERE
    "id" = '51';
```

First you select the table `folio` for the update.
Then you tell it to update `remarks1` through `remarks3` with new values. For `remarks2` and `remarks3` you specify to set them to an empty string. And that's what's going to happen.
Last but not least, you tell it to only apply this update to rows where `id` equals `51`.

So, in order to **only** update `remarks1` you can simply remove the other columns from your update:

```
UPDATE "folio"
SET
    "remarks1" = 'test remark'
WHERE
    "id" = '51';
```

---

**Update:**
I'm by far not a CI expert, but from what I see, I'd change the `$data` array to only contain information for `remark1`:

```
$data     = array(
     'remark1' => $this->input->post('remark1')
);
```

And (from my understanding) it should only update this single column.

Comment: Why is it updated with blank like MySQL does? I'm not adding '' here. It's done by Codeigniter.

Comment: @Dasun Most SQL compliant database systems will set a value to emptystring if you tell them to. This is common and expected behaviour. But I'm not sure how you can tell codeigniter to only update one column.

Comment: @Dasun - if you want help with your CodeIgniter code, you'll need to show some of it. You posted SQL so that's what people helped you with.

Comment: Please see the updated question and tell me where I have gone wrong

Comment: @Dasun I've updated my answer with an idea about the CI problem.